# Add time span in timetable created by schedule class

Tags: formatting, fontsize

How can I automatically print the timespan to each event in a timetable created by the schedule class. Take for example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{schedule}

\begin{document}

\CellHeight{.4in}
\CellWidth{1in}
\TimeRange{12:00-15:00}
\SubUnits{30}
\BeginOn{Monday}
\TextSize{\tiny}
\FiveDay
\TwentyFourHour
\NewAppointment{meeting}{red}{white}
\NewAppointment{workshop}{green}{blue}
\begin{schedule}[Fall Quarter, 2020]
\class{Moral Philosophy}{HOB2 233}{M}{14:00-16:50}
\class{Math Logic}{EIC 128}{T,Th}{11:00-12:20}
\class{Critical Reasoning}{SSL 290}{M,W,F}{13:00-13:50}
\meeting{Departmental Meeting}{HOB2 233}{W}{12:00-12:50}
\workshop{Crit. Reas. Workshop}{HOB2 233}{T}{13:00-13:50}
\class{Office Hours}{HOB2 210}{W,F}{14:00-14:50}
\end{schedule}

\end{document}
```

Now I want to print the time span on the bottom of the corresponding appointment cell without reentering it manually. For  example for "Office Hours" it should print "14:00 - 14:50". How can I do this?

Ideally also the following should work:

- Specify (globally) a separate font size for the time span
- Specify if it is left, center or right aligned on the bottom of a cell
- Specify globally a default if it will be printed or not
- Add an optional argument to overwrite this global setting locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution is to define a new macro `event` to forward the time argument to the appointment title:

```
\newcommand{\event}[5]{%
  #1{#2\newline #5}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
}
```

Just put this macro in front of your appointment parameters.

`\event`s first parameter is the macro name of the appointment, the next 4 arguments are forwarded to the original appointment macro.

The fifth argument (the time) is used also to extend the appointment title.

As complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{schedule}

\begin{document}

\CellHeight{.4in}
\CellWidth{1in}
\TimeRange{12:00-15:00}
\SubUnits{30}
\BeginOn{Monday}
\TextSize{\tiny}
\FiveDay
\TwentyFourHour
\NewAppointment{meeting}{red}{white}
\NewAppointment{workshop}{green}{blue}


\newcommand{\event}[5]{%
  #1{#2\newline #5}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
}

\begin{schedule}[Fall Quarter, 2020]
\event{\class}{Moral Philosophy}{HOB2 233}{M}{14:00-16:50}
\event\class{Math Logic}{EIC 128}{T,Th}{11:00-12:20}
\event\class{Critical Reasoning}{SSL 290}{M,W,F}{13:00-13:50}
\event\meeting{Departmental Meeting}{HOB2 233}{W}{12:00-12:50}
\event\workshop{Crit. Reas. Workshop}{HOB2 233}{T}{13:00-13:50}
\event\class{Office Hours}{HOB2 210}{W,F}{14:00-14:50}
\end{schedule}

\end{document}
```

Your other needs could be defined inside the `\event`-macro. For example:

```
\newcommand{\event}[5]{%
  #1{#2\newline\large #5}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
}
```

---

Another version, without a new macro,but a modification of the exiting code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{schedule}
\makeatletter
\def\draw@appt@box{%
   \ifweekends \relax % if we use 7-days, this won't change
   \else \ifx \the@day\skipday@i \@includefalse \fi % first condition for change
         \ifx \the@day\skipday@ii \@includefalse \fi\fi % second condition for change
  \ifinrange \relax\else \@includefalse \fi %
  \if@include %
  \put(\value{xcoords},\value{ycoords}){\colorbox{\appt@color}{\parbox[t]{\cell@width}{\ %
        \vspace{\box@depth}}}}
  \thinlines
  \put(\value{xcoords},\value{ycoords}){\line(1,0){\value{pu@cell@width}}}
  \put(\value{xcoords},\value{ycoords@bot}){\line(1,0){\value{pu@cell@width}}}
  \put(\value{xcoords},\value{ycoords}){%
        \  \parbox[t]{\cell@width-8pt}{\mbox{}\\ \appt@textsize %
        \ifdim\box@depth>\baselineskip
        \textcolor{\appt@textcolor}{\csname \appt@name @name\endcsname} \\ %
        \ifdim\box@depth>2\baselineskip
        \textcolor{\appt@textcolor}{\csname \appt@name
%%%%%%%%%%%Modifications
%         @location\endcsname}\fi\fi }}\fi} %Original code
        @location\endcsname%
        \hfill \textit{\csname \appt@name @time\endcsname}%
        %%\newline  \csname \appt@name @time\endcsname%
      }\fi\fi}}\fi}
%%%%%%%%%%%Modifications end
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\CellHeight{.4in}
\CellWidth{1in}
\TimeRange{12:00-15:00}
\SubUnits{30}
\BeginOn{Monday}
\TextSize{\tiny}
\FiveDay
\TwentyFourHour
\NewAppointment{meeting}{red}{white}
\NewAppointment{workshop}{green}{blue}



\begin{schedule}[Fall Quarter, 2020]
\class{Moral Philosophy}{HOB2 233}{M}{14:00-16:50}
\class{Math Logic}{EIC 128}{T,Th}{11:00-12:20}
\class{Critical Reasoning}{SSL 290}{M,W,F}{13:00-13:50}
\meeting{Departmental Meeting}{HOB2 233}{W}{12:00-12:50}
\workshop{Crit. Reas. Workshop}{HOB2 233}{T}{13:00-13:50}
\class{Office Hours}{HOB2 210}{W,F}{14:00-14:50}
\end{schedule}

\end{document}
```

The time is added beside the location. I guess this is ok, unless the rooms are not too long (not the real rooms, the room name :) )

As comment: a variant to put the time on a new line, but there I was not set the correct alignment.

Comment: Thanks, quick and dirty, but nice. It works very well except of the aligment. I tried `\newcommand{\event}[5]{%
  #1{#2}{#3 \newline \flushright #5}{#4}{#5}%
}` but this doen't work.